# git repo corrupt w/object directory containing email address

Tags: git

My upstream repo is a bare repo on a macOS 10.12.6 machine running "git version 2.11.0 (Apple Git-81)".

The local repo is on a RHEL6.9 machine running git 2.13.0

I connect upstream using ssh.

`git fsck` on the upstream repo shows:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (1230/1230), done.
broken link from    tree 84a63258fd5215774eba75972a9a69bef72b3d8d
              to    blob e56d3dd863e5571c0ff68a033fa992e4a98688d0
missing blob e56d3dd863e5571c0ff68a033fa992e4a98688d0
```

Further digging shows that `./objects/e5/` is empty, but surprisingly, there is a directory `./objects/e5 (myemail@mydomain.com)/`
which contains a file named `6d3dd863e5571c0ff68a033fa992e4a98688d0`.

What can cause this? This is not the first time the repo has corrupted.

Comment: fwiw, i moved `./objects/e5 (email@domain.com)/` to `./objects/e5/` and fsck is clean. But I'd like to understand and prevent this corruption in the future.

Comment: Do you have any idea when the repository became corrupted like that? Did you use any specific tools on it at this time? Some sort of history cleanup tool or whatnot?'

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, the only interaction with the upstream repo would have been a git push from the local repo after new commits. No branches.

Comment: And just to rule out one typical source of corruption, though I don't think this applies since you mention RHEL, are you using any sort of folder synchronization tool here? Something like DropBox, Google Drive, OneDrive, etc.?

Comment: Do you have hooks in the repository that was corrupted?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, the macOS system's repo is stored in a directory that is in a corporate cloud directory that behaves very similarly to DropBox. The email address in the filename is my git config email _and_ the login email for the cloud service, so its not unthinkable that the cloud service may have replaced the directory with an email-appended name...

Comment: there are no hooks in the corrupted repo

Comment: Could it be that it thinks there was a conflict between multiple copies of that folder? I know from experience that if I edit a file on two different machines one (or both, depending on the tool) is renamed with something to distinguish it. Usually the name of the computer it came from, but different tools use different ways to make the filenames unique. It could very well be that the cloud system did this.

Comment: To be honest, you should **never** store dvcs repositories in such folders. If you need to keep a backup, consider adding another remote to one of your repositories and regularly (or automatically) push to it.

Comment: Does the `e5` folder contain multiple files, now that you've cleaned up the corruption? Does anyone else work on the same repository, from some other machine linked to the same cloud copy? (or even you, just on another machine)

Comment: It is the cloud service. If you'd like to post an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks for your help! https://community.box.com/t5/How-to-Guides-for-Sync/Box-Sync-4-Duplications-With-Email-Address-Added/ta-p/139

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking it over in the comments the answer was as I suspected, you have your repository in a folder mapped to a synchronization tool, such as DropBox, Google Drive, or similar.

These tools need a way to handle conflicts, where multiple synchronized copies of the folders and/or files are edited at the same time before synchronization can catch up.

They typically do this by renaming one or both of the files and adding something that differentiates it from the other copies that were also edited. A typical way would be to append the name of the computer where that copy of the file came from.

As you found out, "Box Sync 4" handles this by appending your account email address, as evident from the [documentation](https://community.box.com/t5/How-to-Guides-for-Sync/Box-Sync-4-Duplications-With-Email-Address-Added/ta-p/139) you linked to:

> In general you will see email appended duplicates with Box Sync if there is an existing item on the Box website with the same name as an item created locally in the same folder location. Box Sync will rename the newer file or folder and add the user’s email address (email@company.com) to prevent conflicts between the two items.

Since it was a folder that was renamed, my guess is that the following happened:

1. On one such linked copy, a folder named `e5` was added, with files
2. This change was then synchronized to the cloud
3. Before the cloud changes could synchronize down to your linked copy, you added a `e5` folder of your own
4. When synchronization caught up, instead of keeping the one folder and just putting all the files in both folders into one, conflict disambiguation was performed, renaming your local folder instead.

---

I'll reiterate what I said in the comments. Folder synchronization tools such as DropBox, Google Drive, OneDrive, Box Sync 4 (thank you for adding another name to my list), should never be used to synchronize DVCS repositories, unless the following is true:

> You only have 1 local copy of the files, anywhere, basically there's two copies of the files, on one computer, and in the cloud.

The reason for this is that if you commit on two different such linked copies, before synchronization catches up, you risk corrupting the repository. Granted, this kind of corruption is *usually* not too bad to fix, but I've seen examples where all hell had broken loose as well.

If you need a backup, consider adding a remote to one of your repositories and automating a push to a repository in the cloud that is hosted by a DVCS aware cloud host.